# можно ли использовать IP как уникальный ключ?

Tags: node.js, сервер, websocket

я делаю небольшое приложение на веб сокетах на ноде. И я не могу понять как мне идентифицировать пользователя. Могу ли я сделать это по айпи? Но если два человека будут сидеть с одного вайфая у них будет один айпи? А если человек зайдет в приложение дважды или больше раз с одного компьютера у них всех будет один айпи?

Comment: 0) IP нельзя использовать как уникальный ключ. 1) хорошо не получится. 2) если ваш "сервер" не в этой же сети, у этих двух клиентов будет один ip-адрес. 3) ip-адрес будет разный, если будет заходит не из одной сети.

Comment: "И я не могу понять как мне идентифицировать пользователя."

-> Cookie

Comment: блин, точно, куки, спасибо)